# Encoding Algebraic Data Types with Aeson in Haskell

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, aeson, to-json

I have the following ADT implementation:

```hs
data FeatureValue =
    FvInt Int
  | FvFloat Float
  | FvText Text
  | FvBool Bool
  deriving Show

data ApiResponse =
    Online [[Maybe FeatureValue]]
  | Offline [[[Maybe FeatureValue]]]
  deriving Show
```

An example value to be encoded might be:

```hs
example :: ApiResponse
example =
    Online [
        [Just (FvInt 10), Nothing, Just (FvText "foo"), Just (FvFloat 1.42)],
        [Nothing, Just (FvBool False), Just (FvText "bar"), Nothing]
    ]
```

which would result in the following JSON:

```json
[
    [10, null, "foo", 1.42],
    [null, false, "bar", null]
]
```

I'm struggling on how to derive the `ToJSON` instance on `FeatureValue` in particular. Documentation on ADT encoding with Aeson is particularly sparse (example, the otherwise great Aelve Guide which features [a glorious "Summary: TODO" for the section concerning ADT encoding/decoding](https://guide.aelve.com/haskell/aeson-cookbook-amra6lk6#item-bfd5vhre)).

Comment: have you tried the official [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.6.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html) documentation? I find Aeson to be one of the best-documented of the commonly-used packages there - if you're struggling with implemented a particular aspect then you could edit your question to give details.

Comment: I did find a mention of "simple sum types" using the example of `data Color = Red | Green | Blue` but I didn't find any mention of how to deal with ADTs holding values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.6.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:ToJSON), we simply need to provide a function of type `FeatureValue -> Value`. The definition of [`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.6.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value) is also documented and fully exported. So just follow your nose.

```
instance ToJSON FeatureValue where
    toJSON (FvInt n) = Number (fromIntegral n)
    toJSON (FvFloat f) = Number (realToFrac f)
    toJSON (FvText t) = String t
    toJSON (FvBool b) = Bool b
```